# Not able to install django and use an existing django project

Tags: python, django

I am studying Django for the first time and everything was going well until the last day. Today when I tried opening my Django project, the terminal returns an error saying :-

```
Unable to create process using
'C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe manage.py runserver'
```

Thinking that it might be an issue with the virtual env, I tried checking my Python Interpreter to make sure I am currently in my venv.

Fortunately, I am currently using my **venv** but Pycharm indicates me to Install Python Packaging Tools.

I tried the link to install it but it notifies a `Non Zero Exit Code(101)` and Invalid Python SDK error.

Googling for the error asked me to check the path in Environment Variables where two are present -

C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\

C:\Users\User1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts\

Recently I had added MingW Compiler to the path and that was it. I've never touched the path of Python.

I would like to mention that there are no errors in creating a new virtual envirnoment nor activating it. But things get worse when I try to pip install django. CMD tells that unable to create process.

Please help! I am actually stuck with my project.

Comment: Try reinstalling python, and don't forget to add the path to environment variables while installation. This might solve the problem.

Comment: I tried that several times. No Luck! Also I have 2 parameters as path for Python

Answer (score 0):

First, try to run any python file (not in your project).

If it works, then the problem is with your django project or the env (try to create a new env and move your files to it).

At last, I think you should reinstall python; this will fix the problem I guess.

Comment: I have already tried reinstalling and fixing paths of python. Python files are working great but coming to django its a mess. Latest update : I am not able to create a virtual env using python -m venv "venvname" . The error returned is Error: Command '['E:\\new\\xenv\\Scripts\\python.exe', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 101.

Comment: Tried creating it with pip install virtualenv "envname" and it works. But activating it won't!

Answer (score 0):

Happy to say that I have fixed the issue.

Steps followed include :

1. Uninstalled Python,Deleted Path,Restarted my pc
2. Downloaded and Installed Python 3.10.2 from the official site.
3. Upgraded pip
4. Installed virtualenv using pip install virtualenv
5. Tested it creating env using - py -m venv "environment name"
6. pip install django works + started a project and the setup was successful.[image]